# Web2py with Multiple Controllers

Tags: web2py

I have a Web2py application in production that contains more than 40 functions in the default controller. Some functions are reasonably complex, consisting of a few hundred lines of code that manage a web of database transactions, while others are relatively simple.

When should developers think about using multiple controllers to manage their application? For example, should we be breaking out controllers that manage a lengthy sitemap from those that manage critical application functions? Are there any impacts on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is needed from a controller, the whole controller must be read in; this will be faster the smaller the controller is.  Whether it is enough of a difference to warrant the effort, that's what profiling is for.

As for when to think about organizing controllers, the best time would be at the start.  After that, you're looking at balancing the amount of effort it will take, and how acceptable it would be to have new URLs (since a new controller will need new URLs to access its functions), against what is to be gained form the exercise.

Comment: I just created separate controllers for a few of the more "complex" functions. Renamed the HTML files, and reconfigured routes.py. The improvement was significant.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other advice given, note that you can move some of the code from your controllers to modules. Therefore, even if a controller has 40 functions, you can still keep the overall controller file very short by moving code from the longer functions to modules and just importing and calling the module functions from the controller.